# How to convert a varchar to a table name?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have an interesting question:
I have a table with trigger names, called `Foo` and the `Foo.TriggerName` field stores trigger names. If I delete a row from `Foo`, I would like a trigger which would drop the trigger with the name `Foo.TriggerName`.

Example:

```
Foo
ID, TriggerName
1,  'Lorem'
2,  'Ipsum'
3,  'Bar'
```

When I am deleting the row with `ID = 3`, I would like to automatically delete the trigger with the name `'Bar'`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use dynamic sql

You can define a trigger for delete on Foo 
and in trigger you can do dynamic sql call

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER foo_before_delete
BEFORE DELETE
    ON Foo
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TRIGGER '||:old.TriggerName||';';

END;
```

Comment: You don't need the extra semi-colon at the end, `:old.triggername ;` is enough.